# How to set a non-blocking delayed response with Node and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send a delayed response to the browser after 500ms has passed.

```
app.post('/api/login', function(req, res) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        res.json({message: "Delayed for half a second"});
    }, 500);
});
```

As you can see from above, I have a simple `post` request. I'm using `setTimeout()` to delay the response, although not sure if this is the NodeJS way by keeping everything "non-blocking".

How can I delay my HTTP response while still keeping my code non-blocking and asynchronous?

Comment: setTimeout isn't blocking, what makes you think it is?

Comment: @Quentin - My bad then. Just assumed it was blocking due to its nature of being a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

its Exactly what you have done
you have delayed http response for 500ms using setTimeout which is non-blocking
case in point if you were to execute a long running code that is blocking one way to make it non-blocking you use setTimeout and pass 000ms

```
setTimeout(function(){
//do some long running staff
}, 0);
```

hope this give you a little bit deeper understanding

Comment: That code will yield to the event loop once, and _then_ block it.

Comment: @robertklep i don't think these depends entirely on event loop rather on the call stack if the call stack hast alot of messages to process then the code will wait longer than the timeout time

Comment: @robertklep why do you deny this, based on the question i think my answer is very valid please check these reliable sources [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: You say that `setTimeout(..., 0)` will make _blocking code_ non-blocking. It does not. If the code would, say, perform a pure calculation that would take up 10 seconds, it will block the event loop for 10 seconds. Using `setTimeout()` (or, preferably, [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg)) will not prevent that.

Comment: please read the last part of [MDN Never Blocking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) please

Comment: Okay, here is some blocking code for you: `while(true){}`. Can you show how your method will make that non-blocking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114866/discussion-between-sachgits-and-robertklep).